# Problema em busca de CEP em Windows Forms

Tags: c#

Adicionei em um formulário do Windows Forms a opção de retornar o endereço através do CEP. Utilizei um web service para obter esses dados e adicionei no seguinte método:

```
private void ConsultaCEP()
    {
        var valor = txtCep.Text;

        try
        {
            var ws = new WSCorreios.AtendeClienteClient();
            var resposta = ws.consultaCEP(valor);

            txtLogradouro.Text = resposta.end;
            txtBairro.Text = resposta.bairro;
            txtCidade.Text = resposta.cidade;
            cbxUf.Text = resposta.uf;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblAvisoCep.Visible = true;
            lblAvisoCep.Text = "Erro ao efetuar busca";
            txtCep.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon;
            txtCep.Clear();
            txtCep.Focus();
        }
    }
```

E chamei este método no evento Leave do textbox do CEP.

```
 private void txtCep_Leave_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConsultaCEP();
    }
```

Porém, ao digitar um CEP inválido, surge a mensagem de erro mas o formulário trava, não sendo possível mudar o cursor para nenhum outro campo que não seja o de CEP. Como resolver este problema?

Comment: Toda vez que você tenta sair do `txtCep` ele dispara o evento `txtCep_Leave_1` que gera um erro e dentro dele tem um `txtCep.Focus();`. Não sei como costumam fazer, mas eu utilizaria o evento de digitação e verificaria a quantidade de caracteres, quando fosse a quantidade referente ao CEP eu chamaria o serviço de consulta.

Comment: Retire o `txtCep.Focus()` que isso quase de certeza deixará de acontecer.

Comment: Se não encontra um cep você joga uma exception?

Comment: Estou votando para fechar porque o autor nunca mais retornou para adicionar esclarecimentos ou confirmar se conseguiu resolver o problema.